# Signing out with devise GETing instead of POSTing in Rails 4 every time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

So this seems to be a pretty common problem. I've combed through the issue tracker on github as well as Stackoverflow but still have not found a solution -besides changing `config.sign_out_via = :delete` to `config.sign_out_via = :get`- which apparently is pretty bad practice.

My issue is that no matter what I try, the client sends a `get` request instead of the prescribed `delete` or `post`.

**In my view**
`<%= link_to "sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>`

**rake routes gives**

```
Anchor$ rake routes
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                                             home#index
        new_user_session GET    /login(.:format)                              devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /login(.:format)                              devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /logout(.:format)                             devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /password(.:format)                           devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /password/new(.:format)                       devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /password/edit(.:format)                      devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /password(.:format)                           devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /password(.:format)                           devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /cancel(.:format)                             devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /                                             devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /sign_up(.:format)                            devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /edit(.:format)                               devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /                                             devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /                                             devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /                                             devise/registrations#destroy
         user_activities GET    /users/:user_id/activities(.:format)          activities#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/activities(.:format)          activities#create
       new_user_activity GET    /users/:user_id/activities/new(.:format)      activities#new
      edit_user_activity GET    /users/:user_id/activities/:id/edit(.:format) activities#edit
           user_activity GET    /users/:user_id/activities/:id(.:format)      activities#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/activities/:id(.:format)      activities#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/activities/:id(.:format)      activities#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/activities/:id(.:format)      activities#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                              users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                              users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                          users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                     users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                          users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                          users#destroy
```

**routes.rb**

```
root :to => "home#index"
  devise_for :users

  resources :users do
    resources :activities
  end
```

**js manifest**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**application.html.erb**
contains the appropriate `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` for including ujs and the rendered header includes:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1">
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1">
```

I had a feeling that it might have something to do with Turbolinks so I tried multiple variations of `data-no-turbolink`, but no cigar. No matter what, the client always sends `Started GET "/users/sign_out"`which keeps routing to UsersController#show.

Any insight would be helpful!

Comment: also, anonymous downvotes are always productive

Comment: Could this be a problem with Turbolinks? Does it still happen if you make that link not be a Turbolink? https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/#opting-out-of-turbolinks

Comment: hey thanks for the comment. I've tried opting out of Turbolinks at both the link level and the parent container. Unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your view

```
<a data-method="delete" href="<%= destroy_user_session_path %>">Logout</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with me :(
For now in Rails 4, all I can do at least now is to route

```
get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
```

*but this approach is vulnerable to CSRF-attack